# Navigation bar back button is not showing?

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

[image: Image Description]I am not getting back button after pushing to next controller through segue

it is just like making a connection between controllers through segue

there is no code included. it is happening in storyboard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### - First:

You should make the **source view controller** (not destination) as **rootViewController** of the navigation view controller. You probably set the segue as push instead of that.

### - Second:

Make sure you don't set the back button item manually anywhere.

Comment: No, I put first controller as a root view controller, in second view  controller , back button is showing after that I pushed to third view controller then back button is not showing. I don't know what I happening.,  it is showing into storyboard but not after running

Comment: Please provide images of the view hierarchy of the third viewController.

Comment: I have edited my question where you find a link for screenshot of third view controller

Comment: Screenshots of the storyboard and view hierarchy, not the design.

Comment: thanks man I got solution. this is happening because of right bar button item which I placed in second view controller